# Naming of button for adding to caller and close

Tags: buttons, graphic-design, close

I have a system which has a dialogue that opens when the user wants to add a particular type of record (which is a list of clients). This dialogue window enables them to search for particular clients and add the specific ones they want. Once they've made their selection they need to click a button that will close the dialogue and pass their selection to the calling window.

However I'm wondering what the best phrasing would be to illustrate this. Currently I have "Add Clients and close' as to say 'You're going to add the clients you've selected to the original window, then close the dialogue'. But then I started thinking that maybe this was a little confusing and perhaps users might be worried it could close the whole program. I'm a little unsure about the ambiguousness of the phrasing.

We're only a small developer company so have no official designer, we do everything ourselves and I've little HCI experience. Is there better way of writing this or am I over-thinking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dialogue is titled `Client selection` or something similar, there is no need to add more info on the button.

<strike>I think a button called <kbd>Validate</kbd> will do.</strike>

---

@EDIT : Since it's not a validation, try <kbd>Add client</kbd> button ! ;)

Comment: Validate? But I'm not trying to validate anything I'm merely trying to pass a selection of records from one window to another and close the window. I don't see how this is validation. P.S. I'm adding, not validating. Should I edit to make this more obvious?

Comment: The user has selected a list of client, he wants to validate his selection to compute it somehow

Comment: I feel this would be even more confusing for the user. In many ways they've validated it themselves; 'I want these guys, here they are, yes they are correct, now I want to add them.'

Comment: And what is wrong with the `Add client` without talking about closing? (if you think the closing part is confusing)

Comment: That actually sounds about right :P Simplicity is sometimes best even though the user might be surprised the first time they add and the dialogue closes. But they'll always expect that afterwards.

Comment: If you have other dialogue which keep even after been used, maybe you should consider to adopt a common behaviour (I recommend to close already used dialogue)

Comment: No, nothing like that we do actually have a couple of other dialogues like this one but they function in the same way; Add, close.